# How to use itshape for different fonts

Tags: italic

The result of `\itshape` or `\textit{}` is the italics of the main font in our document. If I have other fonts set for different environments, I could access their italics by the use of `\fooitalics` via a definition of `\newfontfamily{\fooitalics}[Path]{someitalics.ttf}`. But how can I use italic fonts in a new command which is designed to be workable in different environments with different environment specific fonts?

For example, I want a new command `\qqit` to use double quotes symbol and make text to be italic, if I define it as `\newcommand{\qqit}[1]{{\itshape\qq{#1}}}`, then it works in the environment which uses the main font, but doesn't work for other environments with other fonts.

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{domitian}  % for the main font
\newfontfamily{\notefont}[Path=./fonts/]{LinBiolinum.ttf}  % for note environment
\newfontfamily{\notefontitalic}[Path=./fonts/]{LinBiolinum_Italic.ttf}
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{blanker, breakable, before skip=6pt,after skip=16pt, borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{myblue}}
    \newenvironment{note}{\begin{adjustwidth}{3mm}{0mm}}{\end{adjustwidth}}

\usepackage{textcmds}  % qq for double quotes
\newcommand{\qqit}[1]{{\itshape\qq{#1}}} 

\begin{note}
    In this note, the \qqit{notefont} is used.
\end{note}
In this paragraph, the \qqit{main font} is used.
```

[image]

The first "notefont" is not italics as the main font is not used in that environment.

If I change the command to `\newcommand{\qqit}[1]{{\notefontitalic\qq{#1}}}`, then it uses the 'notefont_italic.ttf' other than the main font italics for "main font":
[image]

Comment: if you define your font families properly, \itshape will simply work. After all in a normal document `\rmfamily\itshape` gives a different result then `\sffamily\itshape`.

Comment: do not use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and `\usepackage{domitian}` with xelatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing `\usepackage{domitian}` with XeLaTeX to begin with. The font is also available as OpenType.

Since I have installed both Linux Biolinum O and Domitian as system fonts, the calls below might have to be adapted to your setting. The main aspect is that you need to properly define a *single* font family for Biolinum (or, better, use `\setsansfont`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{textcmds}  % qq for double quotes

\colorlet{myblue}{blue!60!green}
\tcolorboxenvironment{note}{
  blanker,
  breakable,
  before skip=6pt,
  after skip=16pt,
  borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{myblue},
}
\newenvironment{note}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{3mm}{0mm}\notefont}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\newcommand{\qqit}[1]{\textit{\qq{#1}}}

\setmainfont{Domitian}

\newfontfamily{\notefont}{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}

\begin{note}
In this note, the \qqit{notefont} is used.
\end{note}

In this paragraph, the \qqit{main font} is used.

\end{document}
```

Production notes: I removed `minted` from the libraries because I didn't want to bother with shell escape; I also provided a definition for the `myblue` color.

[image]